# Are the probabilities for a run in a coin toss experiment starting at a certain index independent?

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

I am asking myself the following question:

> Consider $n$ i.i.d. throws of a fair coin and let $I_{k,i}$ be the indicator RV for the event that a run of $k$ consecutive heads starts at the $i$-th throw. Are two such indicator RVs, i.e. $I_{k,i}$ and $I_{k,j}$ for $i \ne j$ independent?

Intuitively I would say no, but I am not sure how to argue that. However, it seems to me that if $I_{k,i} = 1$, then the probability of $I_{k,i+1} = 1$ is high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than starting with just probabilities, think about the events themselves.

If $I_{k, i} = 1$, then that means that flips $i, i+1, \ldots, i+k - 1$ are all heads.

If that's the case, then $I_{k, i+1} = 1$ is the event that flips $i+1, i+2, \ldots, i+k$ are all heads, but since we already know that that's true for most of them, this becomes equivalent to the event that flip $i+k$ is heads.

At this point it should be clear that the events are not independent, but we can finish it off by going back to the probabilities and noting that $P(I_{k, i+1} = 1 | I_{k, i} = 1) = \frac{1}{2} \neq (\frac{1}{2})^k = P(I_{k, i+1} = 1)$ unless $k = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the smallest non-trivial example: $n = 3$, $k = 2$

$2^3=8$ possible 3-roll outcomes.

$I_{3,1}=1$ on HHT and HHH; $I_{3,2}=1$ on HHH and THH.

$P(I_{3,1} = 1) = \frac{1}{4}$, $P(I_{3,2} = 1) = \frac{1}{4}$

$P(I_{3,1} = 1 \land I_{3,2} = 1) = \frac{1}{8}$

$\frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{16} \ne \frac{1}{8} $

They could intuitively seem independent because their indicators overlap as much as they don't, so I see where you might be coming from. In this example, if you restrict the event space to outcomes in which there is a run of $k$ heads, and give each an equal probability of $\frac{1}{4}$, they are independent. That works when $k = n-1$.